# Will Google Maps Geolocation API detect levels in a parking garage?

Tags: android, google-maps, directions, google-geolocation

I want to make a location tracker app, but I want it to be able to detect the user's precise location, for instance what floor in a parking garage is he on, and navigate to/from there. Will Google Maps Geolocation have that precision? Is there something else I can use that will?

Answer (score 1):

Probably not.  The problem is that parking lots tend to be made of thick concrete and steel.  GPS doesn't work well in them-  very inaccurate as the signal has a hard time penetrating.  Its a physical limitation of how GPS works and the frequencies it broadcasts at.  You're lucky if it gets the building right when you're in one.

If we were talking one specific parking lot and you could install hardware you could do it via beacons.  But any generic parking lot, no way.